# Derivation of the formula of the magnetic pressure exerted on a steady surface of current

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

How might one derive the [magnetic pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_pressure) , $ P_B = \dfrac{B^2}{2\mu_0}$ exerted on a surface of current of density $K$? 
(I have observed it to be analogous to the formula of the electrostatic pressure, $ P_E =\dfrac{\epsilon_0E^2}{2}$ and have begun by attempting to produce a derivation analogous to that which Griffiths had given in obtaining it).

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/700947/does-magnetic-force-on-a-current-carrying-thin-slab-depend-on-current-distributi/702806#702806

Comment: This is not exactly correct, because in general there are two values of magnetic field due to two sides of the surface. So net pressure is proportional to difference $B_1^2-B_2^2$. Only in special cases where one of the terms is zero (such as infinite zero-thickness solenoid), is your premise correct.

Answer (score 0):

From Ampère's circuital law (J is current density),

$\mu_0J=\nabla \times B \therefore J=\frac{1}{\mu_0}(\nabla \times B)$

We can apply this to Lorentz force,

$J\times B = \frac{1}{\mu_0}(\nabla \times B) \times B$

When you do some vector calculus identity stuff, you can simplify it to:

$J\times B = \dfrac{(B \cdot \nabla)B}{\mu_0}-\nabla\left(\dfrac{B^2}{2\mu_0}\right) = \kappa \dfrac{B^2}{\mu_0} - \nabla\left(\dfrac{B^2}{2\mu_0}\right)$

where $\kappa$ is a curvature vector. The component with $\kappa$ describes magnetic tension...which is unrelated to your question, but just throwing it out there. This is a relation between current density and a magnetic field which is just Lorentz force.

Comment: The expression $\mathbf J\times \mathbf B$ is discontinuous on a 2D current sheet due to discontinuous $\mathbf B$ there. Thus it is not justified to write down force as integral of $\mathbf J \times \mathbf B$ over volume;the delta from $\mathbf J$ selects value of $\mathbf B$ at the point of discontinuity of $\mathbf B$, which is not a valid use of delta. Valid expression of force density would be $\mathbf J\times \mathbf B_{ext}$ where $\mathbf B_{ext}$ is field due to other sources than the surface current element, but then we can't express $\mathbf J$ via $\nabla \times \mathbf B_{ext}$.