# Is the magnetic field generated by a surface current always a vacuum field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, maxwell-equations

I am wondering about this since usually if there are no current distributions then we would obtain a vacuum field since $\nabla \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \mathbf{j} = 0$ from Ampere's Law.

For the case of a surface current, well the surface current generates a discontinuity in $\mathbf{B}$ across the surface but still, there are no other current distributions out of the surface.

Comment: What do you mean by "vacuum field"? Field for which $\nabla\times\mathbf B =0$? Then the field is not "vacuum field" on the current surface, but is so outside the surface.

Comment: Yes, by vacuum field I mean $\mathbf{B} = 0$. The magnetic field on the surface is not defined in the sense that it has two values (inside and outside limits of $\mathbf{B}$). My main question is if these two values are vacuum fields by definition?

Comment: Magnetic field on the surface can be defined, because the current layer experiences some finite magnetic force (possibly zero). It turns out that in case of flat surface, magnetic field in the layer is arithmetic average of the fields on both sides of the layer.

Comment: Magnetic field in the flat layer is the external magnetic field $\mathbf 
 B_{ext}$, more in this answer of mine https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/702806/31895

Comment: I think there is an inconsistency in what you said. If $\mathbf{B}$ in the layer is just the average of the inside and outside limits, and both inside and outside limits are both vacuum fields... then $\mathbf{B}$ in the layer would also be a vacuum field...

Comment: "Vacuum field" is not a term I use. If by vacuum field you mean $B=0$, then there is no vacuum field on either side of the current layer, because $B \neq 0$ on both sides.

Comment: Vacuum field means $\nabla \times \mathbf{B}^{in} = 0$ or $\nabla \times \mathbf{B}^{out} = 0$

Comment: And what is $\mathbf B^{in}$?

Answer (score 0):

You misconception is probably that if:
$$
\nabla\cdot B=0\\
\nabla\times B=0
$$
then $B=0$ (assuming finite energy). The domain of the field is important, and the result is valid only for the infinite space. In general, $B$ is undertermined and is unambiguously specified by adding boundary conditions.

This is analogous to electrostatics where you think directly in terms of potential. If $\Delta V=0$, you cannot deduce that $V$ is constant. For a compact domain, any harmonic polynomial is a valid solution. The electrostatic analogy shows that you don’t even need discontinuities. The Coulomb field from a point charge is a valid solution after all.

The surface current thus divides your infinite space into separate domains where the magnetic field can be non zero. In any case, if $B=0$ on both sides, then the discontinuity condition is not verified.

There are many examples where you can compute the magnetic field explicitly for surface currents. The easiest one that has finite energy is a uniformly magnetized sphere:
$$
M=\begin{cases}
0 & r>R\\
M_0 & r<R
\end{cases}
$$
Equivalently, it is spherical surface current in the azimutal direction and proportional to the distance to the $z$ axis:
$$
j=j_0\sin\theta\delta(r-R)
$$
In this case, $B$ is determined unambiguously as a dipole field outside and uniform inside.

Note that not only is the field not uniformly zero, but $B$ is non zero in both of the subdomains. Indeed, if you imposed $B=0$ outside the ball, you would get a singularity at the origin and similarly setting $B=0$ in the ball, then the magnetic field would diverge at infinity. In either case yoi would get infinite energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this does not address the question. I know that B is different from 0 in both domains (inside and outside). I am just asking if the inside and outside limits are vacuum fields.

Comment: If your question is whether one of the limits of the fields on a side of the boundary must be zero, then it is no. My example gives a counter example. There is no reason the filed should be zero on one side of the surface, after all Biot-Savart is non local.

Comment: once again, the question is if $ \nabla \times \mathbf{B}$ is different from 0 in both domains (inside and outside).

Comment: $\nabla \times B=0$ inside both domains (by this I mean the topological interior). The current density is only supported on the boundary, you can describe it as a Dirac delta.